# How do I show the past tense?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense

> - She had to knew that I was there there for her help
> - She had to know that I was there for her help
> - She has to knew that I was there there for her help

Please explain in details which statement is correct.

Comment: Only #2. And I would use *...for helping her* instead.

Comment: #2 is correct, but Franky's suggestion is not, since you were there to obtain her help but had not yet. (And also he's reversed who is helping who.)

Answer (score 0):

*had to + base form* is the correct form of the past tense for *have to*, so #2 is the correct option.

However, it sounds weird, I think that could be rephrased as:

> She had to **realise** I was there to help her.

Comment: When do we use had+base form, I'm still confuse about the concept. We always use had+past participles for past perfect. Please help me.

Comment: @user156538 Check the structure *have to* on Google.

Comment: As @Ustanak says, "have to" is a  **completely** different construction from "have": different meaning, and different grammar.

Comment: "Realise" is fine, but "she had to know" is perfectly normal and valid. It's not awkward at all.

Answer (score 0):

Irregular verbs in English sometimes have different words for the past tense, and possibly a non-standard past participle as well.

However, *to X* when used as an infinitive will always be the base form of the verb.  The closest you can get to a "past tense" infinitive is "to have X".

A lot of verbs can be directly followed by an infinitive (some omit the *to* though), and this can be done with *have* and *be*, even though they are also linking/helping verbs.

So *to knew* doesn't work at all based on that.